# Second-order partial derivative of Helmholtz Potential

Tags: thermodynamics

So the lecture notes to my thermodynamics course contain this relation:
$$\left(\frac{\partial^2F}{\partial T^2}\right)_{V,N}=-\frac{1}{\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial S^2}}$$
With no further explanation given. I know that the Helmholtz Potential gives $\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N}=S$ but how does one arrive at $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N}=-\frac{1}{\frac{\partial^2U}{\partial S^2}}$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the differential expression for $dF$, we have:
$
\left( \frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{T}}\right)_{V,N} = -S
$. 
Taking another derivative w.r.t. $T$:
$$
\left( \frac{\partial{F}^2}{\partial{T}^2}\right)_{V,N} = -\left( \frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{T}}\right)_{V,N}.
$$

On the other side, from the differential expression for $dU$, we have:
$
\left( \frac{\partial{U}}{\partial{S}}\right)_{V,N} = T. 
$
Taking another derivative w.r.t. $S$:
$$
\left( \frac{\partial{U}^2}{\partial{S}^2}\right)_{V,N} = \left( \frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{S}}\right)_{V,N}.
$$
We get the required result recalling that $\left( \frac{\partial{S}}{\partial{T}}\right)_{V,N} = \frac{1}{ \left( \frac{\partial{T}}{\partial{S}}\right)_{V,N} }$.

Answer (score 0):

$\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N}=S$, differentiate this w.r.t Temp keeping constant V,N and then substitute from the first equation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't quite follow